# nested vue instance inside vue instance

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I want to put vue instance inside a vue instance so i can use the the dom element as my template and not write the template in the javascript code
ie 
    { template : 'template for the component' }

example :

main.js

```
var v2 = new Vue({
  el: '#child',
  data : {
    msg1 : 'child msg'
  }
});

Vue.component(v2);

var v = new Vue({
  el: '#parent',
  data : {
    msg : 'parent msg'
  }
});
```

index.html

```
 <div id="parent">
        <h1>{{msg}}</h1>
        <div id="child">
            {{msg1}}
        </div>
    </div>
```

as you can see i dont use template i use the el property so my template come from the html on the page the element #parent and #child in this case also as you can see i dont give a name to the component and i just register the vue instance as a component Vue.component(v2);
and not Vue.component('child',v2); for example

now this is working and everything is good but there is no documentation
to this all the examples show how you can register a component with a template to a vue instance

because there is no documentation I am a afraid that in the next version of vue may be it will not work any more

someone know if this is the case or not

Comment: This approach will always work but it is not so useful because you cannot reuse any of the components (first because you should copy-paste the markup, second because with an id you can specify only one element) which is one of the biggest advantages of Vue.js. If you insist on keeping the markup in the HTML, you can use X-templates, this way they will be reusable. Here you can read about it: https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2017/03/24/vue-js-component-templates/

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, I am aware to the disadvantages of this method but I need to add functionality to an existing system and I do not want to change the page and remove parts of it and move it to components, this way i can just add vue as a controller to parts of the existing html pages